# How to resolve unparseable date in java

Tags: java, date

I am working in an application where i have to send some date in controller but if i send the date blank it is getting unparesable date exception ,the datepicker i have  has the date in the format 2015-09-02, and in the controller i am doing

```
java.text.DateFormat outputFormat1 =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.text.DateFormat outputFormat2 =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
interviewPhoneorOnsiteDate = outputFormat2.format(outputFormat1.parse(interviewDate));
```

This code i am using to parse the date according to my format

and the way i am fetching the date is

```
String interviewDate = ParamUtil.getString(uploadRequest, "start-date");
```

but when the date field is blank the exception is occuring,Please anybody help

This is exception

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.msh.InterviewScheduleController.insertCandidateDetails(InterviewScheduleController.java:502)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:148)
... 134 more
```

The actual problem is in this line

```
    Date interviewDateAdded = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

when it is null it can not parse

Comment: `if (interviewDate.equals("")) {...}` or something like that? Another idea would be `try{...} catch(...){...}`. Please show a minimum effort of self-research.

Comment: why do you not use a try/catch ?

Comment: yah but what is the problem i am asking that

Comment: @vincent: Don''t try catch because empty input is not an exceptional case but an expected case. Moreover if you try-catch you cannot distinguish empty inputs (which are expected) from other non-valid inputs (which are not expected). Therefore just check first if input is empty (null or "") and if it is then set interviewDate to null.

Comment: @MikeArgyriou i will try/catch the parse, because the parse could throw an exception.
for lucifer : watch the javadoc for the method parse, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Comment: If you're new to Java in general, find a book or online tutorial. The problem is that you're asking for information that is already present in the Internet, this steals our time, preventing us from solving real problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ParseException` thrown by [`DateFormat.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) as shown in [`API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

> `ParseException` - if the beginning of the specified string cannot be parsed.

```
try {    
    java.text.DateFormat outputFormat1 =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.text.DateFormat outputFormat2 =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    interviewPhoneorOnsiteDate = outputFormat2.format(outputFormat1.parse(interviewDate));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
     // do action if date cannot be parsed
     // return error unvalid date or what you need
}
```

Comment: I have added the exception ,please see

Comment: this is exactly what my code does, catches ParseException, just give to `interviewPhoneorOnsiteDate` value by default if date cannot be parsed.

Comment: i have to vilidate a form where date can not be blank so i can not give default format , if the date is blank i have to shoe some msg,that why i am checking

Comment: I don't know your app structure, how do you send errors to the user? where is this code located? we're not here to magically solve your problems but to make you understand your error, `try {} catch` block is what you need, now make some research and understand what we're telling you, stop asking help without making any effort